# Google docs api returning INVALID ARGUMENT

Tags: google-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

Facing an odd issue of the Google docs API returning status - "INVALID_ARGUMENT" and message as "Request contains an invalid argument" for some documents.

We have an app that authenticates users with Oauth and reads their documents later when needed. Most of the docs are being read perfectly but some docs are giving the error above.

eg URL being requested - https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/1I6wzPgaconzvbozjhQfZdX3qICQSEo-w?

Expecting at least the name of the argument which is being deemed as invalid.